# Which language would be more suitable than the other for manipulating huge graphs, F# or C#?

Tags: c#, f#

Are their advantages to either C# or F# that would make that language more suitable for manipulating huge graphs?

Comment: I don't think the language is so important. Perhaps it would be better to concentrate on the algorithms...

Comment: If you were talking about tree manipulation, I would definitely recommend F#. However, graph manipulation is a different beast. See here for some insights: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2933#comment-43367

Comment: @closers, I don't think this is subjective *and* argumentative. There could be very good reasons to use one or the other.

Answer (score 13):

Neither.

Both C# and F# are excellent languages that poses the capabilities to examine large data structures in an efficient manner.  Virtually any solution coded up in one language could be coded up in the other.  True there would be some syntactic differences and the occasional language construct which doesn't port cleanly between the two.  But neither language has an inherent advantage in this area.

Instead of focusing on the language here I would focus on the algorithm.  That much more than the language will determine the efficiency of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these will compile to the same set of MSIL instructions. There may be some semantic difference at the IL level between the cleanest F# algorithm and the cleanest C# algorithm, but it wouldn't be significant.

As JaredPar said, both are equally capable of efficiently traversing large data graphs.

Comment: -1: "Both of these will compile to the same set of MSIL instructions". Unlikely because F# targets ILX whereas C# only targets vanilla IL. Tail calls are the most obvious example of an IL instruction that F# generates but C# cannot. Conversely, C# has `goto`...