# Size of Serialization in F# vs C#

Tags: c#, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which one is better to manipulate huge graphs F# or C#? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184592/which-one-is-better-to-manipulate-huge-graphs-f-or-c-why)

Would the serialization of a graph in F# be smaller than in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [which one is better to manipulate huge graphs F# or C#? why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184592/which-one-is-better-to-manipulate-huge-graphs-f-or-c-why) Is your other question on the exact same topic not enough?